# moving the code to the activity java class (making two java classes into one)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have codes in two classes

First class is ExampleBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ExampleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false
            );
            if (noConnectivity) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second class is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExampleBroadcastReceiver exampleBroadcastReceiver = new ExampleBroadcastReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

How can I make the two classes into one by passing the code from the ExampleBroadcastReceiver class to MainActivity? Is it possible? Please don't ask why. Thanks.

Comment: "Please don't ask why" .. So, you are already anticipating a lot of people asking this? Maybe that alone should tip you off not to do it

Comment: Thank you for reply sir. But I think I need to merge the two java classes.

Comment: Why do you think you need to merge the classes? Sorry, but there is a good chance that whatever thing you think you're solving by doing that is better solved another way... The short answer is "you can't, the two classes inherit from different base classes for different purposes and there isn't a way to make a single class that extends both base classes"

Comment: Also, please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1174589) if you want to understand why people are asking you why you want to do something.

Comment: When the user starts the program, the MainActivity is started.  When the code in MainActivity detects that the internet is down, it opens an ExampleBroadcastReceiver and issues a Toast message.  I have created dialog boxes in MainActivity.  In the ExampleBroadcastReceiver class, I want to display a dialog box instead of a Toast.  but how can i do it?  Can I open a dialog box in the MainActivity while in the ExampleBroadcastReceiver class?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, you could do that by defining a custom `EventCallback` interface you pass to the broadcast receiver on construction, like the answer below shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java interface to handle an event in MainActivity that occurs in `ExampleBroadcastReceiver`. This way you don't have to merge classes to share an event based data.

```java
public class ExampleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public interface ConnectivityMonitorCallback {
        void onConnectivityChanged(boolean connectivity);
    }

    public ConnectivityMonitorCallback callback;

    public ExampleBroadcastReceiver(@NonNull ConnectivityMonitorCallback eventCallback) {
        callback = eventCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false
            );
            callback.onConnectivityChanged(noConnectivity);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in the MainActivity you handle the event.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExampleBroadcastReceiver exampleBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Define event handling code here which occurs in ExampleBroadcastReceiver
        exampleBroadcastReceiver = new ExampleBroadcastReceiver(new ExampleBroadcastReceiver.ConnectivityMonitorCallback {
            @Override
            void onConnectivityChanged(boolean connectivity) {
                // Handle the event that occured in ExampleBroadcastReceiver
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be helpful to make your example callback take a boolean and show how to call it with `noConnectivity` instead of making a toast like OP was trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since I didn't understand clearly what the OP was trying to do I have writtena general pattern. Now I will update the example.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tested it? Does it work as you need to show a dialog in the activity?

Comment: Yes, everything is working. The dialog is opening in MainActivity as I expected. 